# Silverlight MediaElement Position with generated WAV (performance)

Tags: silverlight, slider, mediaelement, wavmss

I have tied a MediaElement control to a Slider control.
I am getting my stream from a binary field in a SQL Server database.
I am concerned that there may be some performance issues due to the following:
1. I am storing a byte array that is being retrieved from a web service
2. Anytime I do anything with the MediaElement (i.e. reset position, stop playback, resume playback) I have to reset the source of the MediaElement
The code I am using to set the position is as follows:

```
private void ResetPlayerWithPosition(double milliseconds = 0)
{
    // _wmss is a WaveMediaStreamSource from WAVMss.dll
    // audio is of type byte[]
    this._wmss = new WaveMediaStreamSource(new MemoryStream(this.audio));
    this.playbackController.SetSource(this._wmss);
    this.playbackController.MediaOpened += (s, e) =>
    {
        this.playbackController.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
    };
}
```

My concern is that if the file gets to be large, there will be performance degradation in that the code has to wait for the file to be loaded into the MediaElement's source before the position is reset. If this is the case, does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could make it a bit more efficient?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been 1 year 10 months 14 days since I first posted this, and not even a comment or follow-up question. In this time, iOS has made many advancements, Android has released some new flavors, HTML5 and jQuery have matured gracefully, and Microsoft has abandoned Silverlight for Metro.

I have abandoned this solution since support is sparse and on its way to nonexistence. In exchange for Silverlight, I have opted for a HTML5 + jQuery solution. This has enabled me to develop a light weight, Web Method driven, AJAX enabled, browser + device + server independent, cross-platform client in a reduced development time with more flexibility, sustainability, and maintainability.

Silverlight: Another highly innovative yet grossly inefficient technology laid to rest. RIP.